# gcc embedded cortex soft / hard float

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, ld, eabi

Thanks in advance.

I'm using GCC to compile my Code for `STM32F7 ARM Cortex`.

Unfortunately my result always includes [floating point emulation Routines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Soft-float-library-routines.html#Soft-float-library-routines)

```
00200664 00000254 T __aeabi_dmul
00200664 00000254 T __muldf3
00200300 00000276 T __adddf3
00200300 00000276 T __aeabi_dadd
002002fc 0000027a T __aeabi_dsub
002002fc 0000027a T __subdf3
```

Using the Compileflags:

```
CFLAGS_ARCH += -mlittle-endian -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb
CFLAGS_ARCH += -mfloat-abi=hard -mhard-float -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16
CFLAGS_ARCH += -D__FPU_PRESENT
```

How can I disable linking these Functions and see where and why they are used in my Code to use only hard single Float?

If I just do -nostdlib it removes the full stdlib. I just want to use the Hard FPU for performance instead of precise double precision.

Thanks !

Comment: You may have to use the correct compiler flags for it. Please take a look at `-mfloat-abi=name` and             `-mfpu=name`

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. I Extended my Question with my currently used Flags.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing the code but you may have double literals somewhere. Use proper suffixes (1.0f). And be careful with C math functions.